# How to map a column's value to a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new with python, and have a dataset as below:

```
package_name,name,starttime,duration   
com.instagram.android,Instagram,2020-10-19 21:18:57.527,0.116
com.instagram.android,Instagram,2020-10-19 21:26:42.613,3.945
com.facebook.katana,Facebook,2020-10-19 21:26:45.050,1.277
,sudoku,2020-10-30 20:20:45.050,25.277
```

I am trying to add column that contains the category of the application. For example: Facebook and Instagram = 'communication', sudoku = 'games',  ...

How can I accomplish this on a very large dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to *map* a column's value to a lookup table. For this, the `pandas.Series.map()` function is very useful.

[The official docs can be found here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Steps:

- Create a lookup table (or `dict` to be specific)
- Read your data into a `pandas.DataFrame`
- Call the `map` function on the key column to be mapped
- Assign the output to a new column

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a lookup table (dict).
lookup = {'instagram': 'communication',
          'facebook': 'communication',
          'sudoku': 'games'}

# Use DataFrame in OP's question.
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
# Alternatively, the dataset can be read data from a CSV file.
# df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', sep=',')
  
# Map the values from `name` column (lower cased) to the category.
df['category'] = df['name'].str.lower().map(lookup)
```

Output:

```
            package_name       name                starttime  duration     \
0  com.instagram.android  Instagram  2020-10-19 21:18:57.527        0.116   
1  com.instagram.android  Instagram  2020-10-19 21:26:42.613        3.945   
2    com.facebook.katana   Facebook  2020-10-19 21:26:45.050        1.277   
3                    NaN     sudoku  2020-10-30 20:20:45.050       25.277   

        category  
0  communication  
1  communication  
2  communication  
3          games
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I find the different categories of applications?

Comment: My pleasure, hope it's helpful to you.  As the application category logic is 'arbitrary' - this will be a user (you) defined `dict`.  Just add any new applications and categories to the `lookup` dictionary and you're set!

Comment: (Will delete this comment). If the answer has been helpful, please click the tick next to the answer to show it as accepted. This is a standard SO practice, thank you!